# Convert between different kind of sample type

Tags: c++, signal-processing, template-meta-programming, typeconverter

I want to use a template to convert between different sample types

```
template<class T,class U>
void convert(const T* source, U* dest, size_t n)
    {
    do
        {
        double G=double(max(*dest))/max(*source);
        T diff=max(*source) - min(*source);
        *dest=U(makeUnsigned(*source - min(*source))*G/makeUnsigned(diff)
              +makeUnsigned(max(*source) - *source)*double(min(*dest))/makeUnsigned(diff));

        ++dest;
        ++source;
        --n;
        }
    while(n!=0);
    }
```

Now, I want an auto-generated matrix so I can

```
convert[from][to](source,dest,n);
```

where each element reffers to the right version. I know that I have to cast function pointers here (each element needs to be pointer to function taking const void*,void* size_t which is equivalent anyway).

Can I do that?

Comment: I don't understand. `convert` is a function; what is `convert[from][to]` supposed to do? Or do you mean `convert<from, to>`?

Comment: @sftrabbit An auto-generated matrix of callable items so I do not need MxN cases in nested switch-case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, write this:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
U convert( T const& src );
```

because everything else should be written with template metaprogramming.  The nice thing about doing this is you can specialize your `convert<int, double>` and your `convert<std::string, int>` if you need to.

Next, write this:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
void convert_buffer( T const* src, U* dest, size_t n );
```

which simply calls `convert` above in a loop.  I split this into two functions, because the possibly non-uniform code goes in `convert`, and calling a function with its body visible has basically zero overhead.

And then write this:

```
typedef void(*blind_converter)(void const*, void*, size_t);
template<typename T, typename U>
void convert_blind_buffer( void const* src, void* dest, size_t n ) {
  return convert_buffer( reinterpret_cast<T const*>(src), reinterpret_cast<U*>(dest), n );
}
```

which encapsulates the casting, and doesn't require you to do a theoretically invalid pointer type cast.  It is "convert blind" a buffer -- blind, in that it takes `void*`s.

Next, we don't want to maintain your NxN array manually.  A type to store your ordered list of types:

```
template<typename... Ts>
struct type_list {};
```

And then we write some metaprogramming to build the NxN array:

```
template<typename Src, typename DestList>
struct make_convert_one_way;
template<typename Src, typename... Ds>
struct make_convert_one_way< Src, type_list<Ds...> > {
  std::array< blind_converter, sizeof...(Ds) > operator()() const {
    return { convert_blind_buffer< Src, Ds >... };
  }
};

template<typename list>
struct make_convert_array;

template<typename... Ts>
struct make_convert_array< type_list<Ts...> > {
  std::array< std::array<blind_converter, sizeof...(Ts) >, sizeof...(Ts) > operator()() const {
    return { make_convert_one_way< Ts, type_list<Ts...> >... };
  }
};

typedef type_list< int, char, double > my_list;
auto convert_array = make_convert_array<my_list>()();
```

or something along those lines.

If your source and dest types are not uniform, the above would have to be modified to take two `type_list`s, but there isn't anything fundamentally difficult about it.

The next useful thing would be the ability to map from a type to an index in the above array, because maintaining that should be the compiler's job.

```
template<typename T, typename List, typename=void>
struct index_of;
template<typename T, typename T0, typename... Ts>
struct index_of<T, type_list<T0, Ts...>, typename std::enable_if<
  std::is_same<T, T0>::value
>::type >: std::integral_constant< std::size_t, 0 > {};
template<typename T, typename T0, typename... Ts>
struct index_of<T, type_list<T0, Ts...>, typename std::enable_if<
  !std::is_same<T, T0>::value
>::type >: std::integral_constant< std::size_t, index_of<T, type_list<Ts...>::value+1 > {};
```

which lets you do this:

```
static_assert( index_of< int, my_list >::value == 0, "all is well!" );
```

Now, you might want to wrap this up in some type dressing.  A strategy might look like this:

```
template<typename List>
struct EnumDressing;
template<typename... Ts>
struct EnumDressing<type_list<Ts...>> {
  enum type {
    e_begin = 0,
    e_end = sizeof...(Ts),
  };
  template<typename T>
  static constexpr type value() {
    return static_cast<type>( index_of<T, type_list<Ts...> >::value );
  }
};
```

where we have the `EnumDressing<my_list>::type` as the type of an `enum` that represents integer names for your types, and the values of it can be gotten via `EnumDressing<my_list>::value<int>()`.  Naturally you clean this up with `typedef`s:

```
typedef EnumDressing<my_list> Types;
typedef Types::type eType;

struct typed_array {
  eType type;
  void* buff;
  size_t n;
};
void do_convert( typed_array src, typed_array dst) {
  Assert(src.n == dst.n);
  convert_array[ src.type ][ dst.type ]( src.buff, dst.buff, std::min( src.n, dst.n ) );
}
template<typename T, size_t N>
typed_array make_typed_array( T (&arr)[N] ) {
  return { Types::value<T>(), reinterpret_cast<void*>( &arr[0] ), N };
}

int main() {
  double d[100];
  int i[100];
  do_convert( make_typed_array( d ), make_typed_array( i ) );
}
```

with naturally actual use cases separating the creation of the `typed_array` from its use.